# execute an exe on windows using groovy script

Tags: groovy, cmd

I am trying to execute a MIR3 (notification system) exe from the Groovy console:

```
def proc = "cmd /c C:\\Users\\AAithal\\Desktop\\MIR3\bin\\inConsole -H \"company.mir3.com\" -u \"user\" -p \"password\" -I -i \"Server\"".execute();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
println "proc"
```

But get an error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The path I have in the script is correct and I am able to execute the same from Windows CLI and getting the required output.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please include your code/output as text instead of as an image.

Comment: @doelleri, here it is:-
def proc = "cmd /c C:\\Users\\AAithal\\Desktop\\MIR3\bin\\inConsole -H \"company.mir3.com\" -u \"user\" -p \"password\" -I -i \"Server\"".execute();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
println "proc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a load of arguments it's sometimes better to user ProcessBuilder e.g.

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
//def args = ['cmd', '/c', 'dir']
def args = ['cmd', '/c', 'C:\\Users\\AAithal\\Desktop\\MIR3\\bin\\inConsole', '-H', 'company.mir3.com', '-u', 'user', '-p', 'password', '-I', '-i', 'Server']
def proc = new ProcessBuilder( args )
Process process = proc.start()
process.consumeProcessOutput( sout, serr )
process.waitForOrKill( 2000 )
println sout
```

I've included the commented out `def args = ['cmd', '/c', 'dir']` line so you can test that everything works with a simple example then move onto the more complicated call.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it worked fine. I am trying to replace a variable in one of the command switches something like below:

String MIR3Name = 'Server'
// println "$MIR3Name"


def args = ['cmd', '/c', 'C:\\Users\\AAithal\\Desktop\\MIR3\\bin\\inConsole', '-H', 'company.mir3.com', '-u', 'user', '-p', 'password', '-I', '-i', '$MIR3Name']


THe value of the variable defined above is not getting substituted in the command. I used single/double quotes, flower brackets etc. Please let me know the right syntax as i try it out parellely as well.

-Abhi

Comment: just putting MIR3Name in the array should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike, this worked fine:)

```
def args = ['cmd', '/c', 'E:\\MIR3\\bin\\inConsole', '-H', 'company.mir3.com', '-u', 'user', '-p', 'password', '-I', '-i', MIR3Name, '-X', msgdata]
```