# Generate authentication token for each request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a rather unique situation in jmeter where I need to do load-testing on our authentication federation. This means I need to generate a unique authentication token from a federated token server for each request and because the tokens expire after 5 minutes, I can't use `__StringFromFile`. I need to consume the token as soon as it is produced.

I can prepare an executable that outputs the token to its STDOUT. Is there a way for jmeter to execute a program and consume its output for each request - something like `__ExecuteAndReadStdOut(C:\path\to\program.exe)`?

Comment: Using JSR223 PreProcessor with groovy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812005/execute-an-exe-on-windows-using-groovy-script can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler):

[image]

the program output will be normally available as a SampleResult so you will be able to read it fully or partially using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/)